# Binding HTML form into Entity Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jpa, binding, dto

I have quite complicated JPA Entity. On my page there is a form which, after being filled, creates the entity.

However entity contains few @Embedded objects, whose fields need to be filled too.

lets assume an entity like this one:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    @Embedded
    private PersonalData personalData;
}
```

and @Embeddable objects:

```
public class Address {
    private String city;
    private String street;
    //and so on..
}

public class PersonalData {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String nameAndLastname;
    //and so on..
}
```

In this situation, is it possible to bind form from HTML page into this entity directly?

I thought about creating some DTO object that has all requierd fields that form has and then, convert that UserDTO into User entity object.
However I think it will bring me more complexity and redundant code. (is it not anti-pattern?)

I could make huge list of @RequestParam's inside controller's method instead of @ModelAttribute binding, but the code becomes so long and not elegant.

How to make it work elegant?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add your object to model and fill the form with embedded paths

```
model.addAttribute("user", new User());

<form:form id="user" (...)>
    <form:input path="user.address.city" />
(..)
```

Comment: so when entering the register page, the page should have model of my new User() and its going to be filled after form submiting? is it possible to be done in Freemarker? i am quire sure it is

Comment: I have never done anything with Freemaker, btw why do you use Freemaker against JSP and spring forms ?

Comment: I reckon Freemarker to be not so out-dated as JSP. JSP code is quite wordy.. So I stated to return .ftl files from my controllers